# How to get same output from rails query by running rake task and running the same query in the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have defined the below rails query in a rake task which prints the billing_ids array value in the terminal when I run it. If I try to run this query in rails console something like this-

rails console

```
irb(main):008:0> Office.all.each do |office|
irb(main):009:1* billing_ids=[]
irb(main):011:2*         office.issues.where("issues.amount > 0").each do |issue| billing_ids << issue.billings.where("billings.date < ?", Message.last.date).order(:date).last
irb(main):012:2> end
irb(main):013:1> end
```

It prints the list of offices. But instead, I want it to print the array values of billing_ids in rails console. How can I achieve that?

rake task

```
Office.all.each do |office|
  billing_ids=[] #initialize array
  office.issues.where("issues.amount > 0").each do |issue|
    billing_ids << issue.billings.where("billings.date < ?", Message.last.date).order(:date).last.id #add id to array
  end
  puts "{billing_ids.map(&:id)}"
end
```

update added

```
irb(main):015:0> billing_ids=[]
=> []
irb(main):016:0> Office.all.each do |office|
irb(main):017:1* office.issues.where("issues.amount > 0").each do |issue|
irb(main):018:2* billing_ids << issue.billings.where("billings.date < ?", Message.last.date).order(:date).last.id
irb(main):019:2> end
irb(main):020:1> puts "#{billing_ids}"
irb(main):021:1> end
```

This still gives offices instead of puts statement

Comment: both the tasks are different, one in `rails c` has `company.casefiles` while the `rake task` has `office.issues`. You need to clearly specify what you need .

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. In the rake task you have an explicit `puts "{billing_ids.map(&:id)}"`. But your console code doesn't have this `puts`. Why do you expect both to generate the same output if one not calling `puts` at all?

Comment: You are using `.last.id` in rake task, `billing_ids` already contains ids, no need to `map(&:id)`. Also, you can put `billing_ids=[]` outside of `Office.all` otherwise, it will reset after each loop.

Comment: `puts "{billing_ids.map(&:id)}"` prints string! `puts "#{billing_ids.map(&:id)}"` prints array. Add `#` tag, before starting curly braces.

Comment: @gautam i added it by mistake. I have fixed it now.

Comment: @7urkm3n I have added the update in the question. But it still shows the offices instead of billing_ids

Comment: Can you include an example of the schema and desired output? Seems like an extremely overcomplicated solution to a simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do exactly what you have in your rake task and it will work -

```
Office.all.each do |office|
  billing_ids=[] #initialize array
  office.issues.where("issues.amount > 0").each do |issue|
    billing_ids << issue.billings.where("billings.date < ?",Message.last.date).order(:date).last.id #add id to array
  end
  puts "#{billing_ids.map(&:id)}"
end
```

You are missing `puts "#{billing_ids.map(&:id)}"` in `rails console`

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a really overcomplicated and ineffective solution to something that can be solved with a simple join:

```
Billing.joins(:issue)
       .where('issues.amount > 0')
       .where('billings.date > ?', Date.yesterday)
       .group(:id, :date) # pk is required on Postgres
       .order(:date)
       .ids
```